# Vagrant synced folder permissions

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I have set up a synced folder in Vagrant, from my Windows host to the guest. Initially the permissions on the files were too open so I added the following mount options:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../my-folder", "/home/vagrant/my-folder",
    mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"]
```

However, I need to add execute permissions on a single file within this folder. `chmod +x file` has no effect. Is there a way to allow a single item in  a shared folder to be executable/have different permissions to the rest of the items in the folder?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the end, I came up with two solutions:

1) Accept all the files being executable

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../my-folder", "/home/vagrant/my-folder",
    mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=777"]
```

2) Use the rsync method to synchronise the folders

```
config.vm.synced_folder "../ansible-provision", "/home/vagrant/ansible", type: "rsync",
    rsync__exclude: ".git/"
```

Each method has its own drawbacks, but the first was quickest to implement and acceptable for my use case, so I went with that.

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue with folder permissions. I'm using virtualbox on Mac OSX. I added the owner and group options which fixed my issue of not being able to write to a cache directory on the server. Update to include folder and file modes.

```
srv.vm.synced_folder server["synced_folder"]["src"], server["synced_folder"]["dest"], create: true, group:'vagrant', owner:'www-data', mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"]
```

Comment: This solution may not work for a new initialization of vagrant because the custom user and/or group may not exist in the box.

Comment: @MingalevME I'm doing this for the Apache user and group (www-data) on Ubuntu, before Apache is installed, and it works fine. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305170/is-it-ok-to-have-files-owned-by-a-non-existent-user

Comment: Could a different approach be to add the www-data user to group vagrant in your provisioning script? That way owner user and group could remain vagrant but user www-data would still have vagrant's permissions. Just a thought...