# Unable to make file executable inside vagrant ssh

Tags: ssh, vagrant, grav

I'm trying to get the Grav CMS working inside my vagrant box but having trouble with permissions.

I've sshed into the box using `vagrant ssh` and traverse inside `/var/www/public` When I try running `bin/gpm install admin` I get a permission denied error.

So I go inside the bin folder and run ls -la and notice gpm and grav aren't executable:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant     204 Nov 12 17:16 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 vagrant vagrant     748 Nov 12 15:40 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant 1705467 Nov  7 12:14 composer.phar
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant    2171 Nov  7 12:14 gpm
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant    1408 Nov  7 12:14 grav
-rw-rw-rw- 1 vagrant vagrant    4281 Nov  7 12:14 plugin
```

I've run `sudo chmod +x gpm` and nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong??

Comment: is `/var/www/public` shared with your host or did you deploy grav directly in the VM ?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your Vagrant file synced_folder `mount_options` to:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www",
mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=777"]
```

The first two arguments above (".", and "/var/www") aren't relevant, leave them as whatever is currently in your Vagrantfile. The important part to change is the mount_options.

**Note:** You have to run `vagrant reload` for the changes to take affect.

I got this answer [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35807568/vagrant-synced-folder-permissions).